# Rails4: keep locale param in root route when using rails engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, rails-engines

When I using a scope with locale param like this:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    resources :users
    ...
  end

  mount MyEngineApp::Engine => "/engineapp"

end
```

and in my Engine:

```
MyEngineApp::Engine.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    ...
  end
end
```

I have urls like this:

```
http://domain.tld/en/users
```

and

```
http://domain.tld/engineapp/en
```

I'd like to have url for my Engine like:

```
http://domain.tld/en/engineapp
```

I can do this by removing scope from Engine route and doing:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    resources :users
    ...
     mount MyEngineApp::Engine => "/engineapp"
  end
end
```

But, if I do this, my links looks like:

```
http://domain.tld/en/engineapp?locale=fr
```

So my question, how can I pass a param to the root route from an engine because I think the problem is here.

Here is my base ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  # before_filter :set_default_url_options
  before_filter :set_locale


  def default_url_options(options={})
    {
      host:   Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host],
      locale: I18n.locale
    }
  end

  protected

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

end
```

And my Engine ApplicationController:

```
module MyEngineApp
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
  end
end
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

It's working with:

```
  def url_options(options={})
    {
      host:   Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host],
      locale: I18n.locale
    }
  end
```

Instead of default_url_options.